# How do I programatically create a Bean 'instance' in code?

Tags: entities, installation, blocks

I am trying to make a sort of `hook_setup_beans()` function (similar to `hook_setup_blocks()`) to create some bean instances by default when a user turns on a bean_example module I am making. This would be called from `hook_install()`.

Is there a standard path for doing this?

I am playing with `bean_create()` and `bean_save()` right now.

Thanks

p.s. I also asked this at https://drupal.org/node/2173783

Answer (score 1):

Creating bean instance programmatically.
https://drupal.org/node/1436186

```
<?php
  $bean = bean_create(array('type' => 'my_bean_type'));
  $bean->label = 'Administrative Label';
  $bean->title = 'Bean Title';
  $bean->delta = 'bean-machine-name';
  $bean->field_block_content = array(
    'en' => array(array(
      'value' => '<p>Text</p>',
      'format' => 'wysiwyg_editor',
    )),
  );
  $bean->save();
?>
```